# XFS partition in Volume Group is suddenly showing up as Atari partition

Tags: filesystems, xfs, volume

I have a server with a large amount of data stored in an XFS partition within a Volume Group spanning a couple physical drive and numerous segemnts/extents.

Suddenly, in the last couple hours, the XFS partition has developed a problem and now shows up in the system as an "Atari filesystem" which can't be mounted. In fact, the system can't boot unless I comment out the line in fstab which mounts the partition to /srv.

How can I fix this and mount the partition as XFS once again without losing my data?

I'm currently running xfs_repair (`xfs_repair -n /dev/mapper/vg-server`) and it figures out immediately that the primary superblock has a bad magic number, and it looks for the secondary superblock and eventually finds one, but doesn't seem to be able to do anything with it.

OK....well, I tried all kinds of things and couldn't recover the data so I formatted everything and re-assembled the disks as a RAID 1 array and restored what I could figuring that at least I had some redundancy now.

A couple months later, I ran into the same problem with the XFS partition losing it's magic number, etc. But this time the problem spanned both disks in the array and, again, I am unable to save the data.

I can't get the system to recognize the partitions on the disks and also can't format the partitions or create file systems on them. If I boot the computer form a CD I can format the drives and create file systems, read/write files etc. but as soon as I reboot the machine I lose the disk partitions again.

What is likely going on here? Is it likely the disk controller on the motherboard? I don't seem to have a problem with the first two disks SATA0 and SATA1, but 2 thru. 6 don't seem to retain their partitions for some reason. This is like the third motherboard I've put in this box in as many years. It doesn't seem likely to me, but I don't know what else would explain it.

Comment: Hardware error, software error, user error, kernel bug, malware, anything is possible is here...

Comment: What makes it lose the partitions and also prevents me from recreating them or formAtting the disks?